# Saving a Datatable to an existing Sqlite database without looping through 300,000 records

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I have created a 345,000 row datatable by importing numerous csv files. I want to save this datatable to an existing sqlite database without having to add each row individually.
Can this be done?  In the same way that a Datatable can be filled with that: `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` can I perform the reverse in a similarly easy way?
I have tried:
'AllEODDataAdapter.Update(DTAllEODData)'
although it doesn't get an error it also does not add any values to the sqlite database.
Any help is appreciated
Brad

Answer (score 0):

If calling `Update` doesn't throw an exception but doesn't save anything then that must be because there is nothing to save. You have to have changes in your `DataTable` to save for them to be saved. How did you populate your `DataTable` in the first place? If it was by calling `Fill` on a data adapter then there will be no changes in that `DataTable` because the `RowState` of each row will be `Unchanged`. If you expect to insert data then the `RowState` has to be `Added`. If you're calling `Fill`, you can set the `AcceptChangesDuringFill` property of the data adapter to `False` and then `AcceptChanges` will not be called and all `RowStates` will remain `Added`, making the data ready to insert. When you call `Update` on the data adapter to save the data, make sure that you have set the `InsertCommand` appropriately.

Comment: Thank you user18387401, I have added the line 'AllEODDataAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False' before the adapter.fill command.  This still didn't work.  Could you show an example of the InsertCommand?  - Brad

Comment: "doesn't work" is never an acceptable explanation. You ALWAYS need to explain exactly what happens. Did you check that the `RowState` of each `DataRow` in your `DataTable` was `Added` before calling `Update`? Don't make assumptions. Look with your own eyes. Once you know that's the case, what actually happens when you call `Update`? It will either throw an exception, return zero or return a non-zero value. Which is it?

Comment: How do I check the RowState of each DataRow when I am not iterating through the datatable?

Comment: It's not for us to teach you the basics. If you don't know what property you need to look at then we can tell you that but you need to know how to look at that property. If you don't know how to use the debugger then stop what you're doing and learn. A question on the language shouldn't include a tutorial on how to use the IDE.

Comment: Have you defined an Insert Command in your data adapter?

Comment: I am using sqlitecommandbuilder to create an insert command, which it does.  I will look further into this.